# How to verify if countdown reaches 0

Tags: javascript

I want to verify the timer from Mike Gieson countdown if is 0 to load the next page if else to place a message until now i have the next code

```
var a = new Countdown({time: 25,
                                    width:100,
                                    height:40,
                                    style       : "boring",
                                    onComplete  : countdownComplete ,
                                    rangeHi:"second"
                                    });
function countdownComplete()
    {
      window.location.href='start.php' ;
    }
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{
  return "Are you shure you whant to leave this page? ";
}
```

Comment: what is `Countdown`? is your custom object? please show the code

Comment: @Murali - JS doesn't have a built-in `Countdown` object, so...

Comment: is the countdown v2.0 from Mike Gieson javascript

Comment: @RaduSua, Please add the link to the library you refered. I googled and found one, which you removed again in your edit

Comment: http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a flag that you set when countdown onComplete event fires and review the flag on the beforeunload event. If the flag is set, the count down already finished.

Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function() {
                var countDownCompleted = false;             

                var countdown = new Countdown({time: 25,
                    width:100,
                    height:40,
                    style:"boring",
                    onComplete: countdownComplete ,
                    rangeHi:"second"
                });
                function countdownComplete(){
                    countDownCompleted = true;
                    window.location.href='start.php' ;
                }
                window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                    if(!countDownCompleted) {
                        return "Are you sure you want to leave this page? ";.
                    }
                }
        })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='start.php'>Go to Start</a> and you will get a message asking if you really want to leave the page
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I whant if they press the button to leave the page or to refresh the page to be sent to another page the rest of the script works 100%

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an event in which occurs then you shows an message. Just put an message to an html element when page loaded like this:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("messageID").innerHTML = "Your message goes here.";
    }
```

and remove message when timer receive 0.

```
    function countdownComplete() {
        //Remove message
        document.getElementById("messageID").innerHTML = "";
        window.location.href = 'start.php';
    }
```